# C# EWS API - Failing to connect to office.com for email. Deprecated?

Tags: c#, outlook, office365, exchangewebservices

Office365 is no longer allowing my C# app to log into the mailbox via the EWS API. Has this library been deprecated? This fails:

`ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013_SP1);`

The error I get when trying is

```
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestException' in Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll

Additional information: The request failed. The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
```

I was told they are no longer accepting connections from anything older than 16.0.4600.1000, which is Office 2016.

Does this make any sense? It fails from multiple hosts at different sites, so I know it's not related to the network on our side.

Answer (score 0):

`Exchange2013_SP1` works fine. Even `Exchange2010_SP1` works perfectly. You might want to include the exact error message that you get back.

Comment: Please see edited question for errors.

Comment: Are you using a hard coded url? Or Autodiscover? Which line of your code throws that exception?

Comment: I am using `service.Url = new Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/ews/exchange.asmx");`

My code throws an error after that when I try to search my inbox.

Comment: Do you get an error only when searching? How about other operations?